# Magento 2 on closing modal window prevent page from scrolling back to top

Tags: model, magento2

guys, I am using Magento model for popup when I close the model it scrolls to the top. Anyone know how to stop scrolling top. I want to stay where I close the popup.
I am using default settings and default close button

```
<button class="action-close" data-role="closeBtn" type="button"><span>Close</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a  CSS issue, you have to set your `"overflow"` attribute on `<body>` tag accordingly. like in my case it worked with this CSS property.

```
   overflow: unset;
```